# Web camera light stays on after stream is stopped

Tags: javascript, html, web, webrtc, webcam

I am building a project that captures an image from the webcam in the browser. After the image is taken, I no longer need to use the camera, so I am trying to stop it with the following function:

```js
function stopCamera(container) {
    console.log("Stopping the camera.");

    video = container.querySelector('.video-streamer');

    console.log(video);

    video.srcObject = null;

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(
        function (stream) {
            console.log(stream.getTracks().length);

            stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                console.log("Found a stream that needs to be stopped.")
                track.stop();
            });

            console.log(stream.getTracks().length);
        }).catch(
            function (error) {
                console.log('getUserMedia() error', error);
            });

}
```

However, even after the function is called, the webcam access light stays on, and I see that the browser (both Firefox and Chrome) still show that the page is using the camera.

What is missing in the code above?

Comment: As replied on Twitter, this snippet does work for me in Edge Chromium, however it grabs the camera again with `getUserMedia`, and if I comment out that entire block, so it's only the setting of `srcObject` to null that kills that the camera, the light also goes out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` returns a *new* stream (a clone), not the existing stream.

You have to stop ***all*** tracks from ***all*** stream clones returned from different calls to `getUserMedia`, before the light goes out.

In your case, that includes the tracks of the stream you're already playing. Use the following:

```
function stopCamera(container) {
  const video = container.querySelector('.video-streamer');

  for (const track of video.srcObject.getTracks()) {
    track.stop();
  }
  video.srcObject = null;
}
```

Once all tracks are stopped, the light should go out instantly.

If you neglect to do this, the light should still go out 3-10 seconds after `video.srcObject = null` thanks to garbage collection (assuming it was the lone held reference to the stream).

If you've created any track [clones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/clone), you need to stop them too.

Comment: thank you, that works! It seems like that is not instant and can take ~5-10 seconds for the light to go off. Is that expected?

Comment: @DenDelimarsky that sounds like you didn't get them stopped, and like garbage collection instead. Light should go out instantly if you've stopped all tracks. Make sure there are no errors in web console. Are you perhaps calling `getUserMedia` more than once?

Comment: good point - I found a place where I was not properly disposing of the stream. Thank you again for looking over this!

Comment: If the camera is attached with USB as external then lights still stay. If the stream got from lappy default camera then calling stop() function closing camera light but not externally connected devices. Tried multiple times but no use. Can someone help me?